# How to use sendKeys into ckeditor text area using java selenium

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, iframe, automated-tests

### How can I send keys to Reach text area in java selenium.

### Here is the HTML code include Iframe:

```
<div class="col-sm-11">
<textarea class="ckeditor ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-dirty ng-valid-parse" ng-class="{true:'validation-error'}[submitted]" placeholder="Enter text ..." ck-editor="" ng-model="NewTicket.Message" name="Message" style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" aria-invalid="true"/>
<div id="cke_Message" class="cke_1 cke cke_reset cke_chrome cke_editor_Message cke_ltr cke_browser_gecko" lang="en" aria-labelledby="cke_Message_arialbl" role="application" dir="ltr">
<span id="cke_Message_arialbl" class="cke_voice_label">Rich Text Editor, Message</span>
<div class="cke_inner cke_reset" role="presentation">
<span id="cke_1_top" class="cke_top cke_reset_all" style="height: auto; -moz-user-select: none;" role="presentation">
<div id="cke_1_contents" class="cke_contents cke_reset" role="presentation" style="height: 200px;">
<span id="cke_50" class="cke_voice_label">Press ALT 0 for help</span>
<iframe class="cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset" frameborder="0" src="" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" title="Rich Text Editor, Message" aria-describedby="cke_50" tabindex="0" allowtransparency="true"/>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<span class="ng-binding ng-hide" style="color:red" ng-show="newTicketForm.Message.$invalid && submitted" aria-hidden="true">Content is required</span>
</div>
```

*I try to use below method using Iframe class name but I couldn’t send data to it. Here is the Selenium code*

```
for (String handle002 : driver.getWindowHandles()) 
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(handle002);
        Thread.sleep(500);
          for (String handle001 : driver.getWindowHandles()) 
            {
    driver.switchTo().window(handle001);
    Thread.sleep(500);
  driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset")));
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
  WebElement body=driver.findElement(By.className("cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset"));
  body.sendKeys("Test");
  driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
            }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: But here text area element looks outside the iframe, so why are you going to switch frame??

Comment: Could you share the HTML code of inside the iframe as well?? Let us know where do you want to set value, in above present text area or inside iframe text area??

Comment: And also tell me why are switching to window??? Is this texteditor opens in new window??

Comment: Actually no need to add the switching windows. It is not opening separate window. 
For whole Reach text area code, I added. If you give but it’s has lot of functions.

Comment: Do you want to sendKeys on this text area `<textarea class="ckeditor ng-untouched ng-empty ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-dirty ng-valid-parse">`??

Comment: yes i want to add into "textarea class="ckeditor"". but i try t send the data using - driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea[ng-model='NewTicket.Message']"));

Comment: But as I'm seeing in your provided HTML this text area is outside the iframe so no need to switch frame...just try without switching into iframe..

Comment: yes i try this. Code is here. WebElement body=driver.findElement(By.className("cke_wysiwyg_frame cke_reset"));  body.sendKeys("Test");

Comment: You should try as `WebElement body=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea.ckeditor")); body.sendKeys("Test");` and let me know..

Comment: i tried, it's shows  org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible Code here:-        `WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("textarea.ckeditor"));     body.sendKeys("Test");`

Comment: Oh yes it's style property looks display none means it's not visible..I think this is not the right text area where you want to sendKeys, try as `driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame");WebElement body=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//html/body"))‌​; body.sendKeys("Test");` and let me know..

Comment: not working. event i added with 4 loop also. please tell me do you have any idea where get wrong.

Comment: Could you share whole HTML of this texteditor??

Comment: whole code i can't add to this but i added to google driver. plz check from this link. [Link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxLcOP1SlqMDamJQalNnMlY1NEE)

Comment: Plz check this [link](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ezT7qnDIM1HCzV3D1q5IV5cYD4qh1iLd9GYOjQUVgiA/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Ok, I have got the solution, try with provided answer and let me know..:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have got the solution after seeing your provided HTML, you should try using `WebDriverWait` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("iframe.cke_wysiwyg_frame.cke_reset")));

WebElement body = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.tagName("body")));
body.sendKeys("Test String");

//Now after entering text into texteditor switch back to default content 
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: Thankz It's works. can you please tell which scenarios i have to use. and one more questing after i added to this code and add below code and click event but itz not working `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".btn.btn-chatcust1.ng-binding")).click();`  but same code i added before text area itz works.

Comment: You need to switch to default content after performing stuff inside textbox as `driver.switchTo().defaultContent();` then use other stuff